# Модификатор доступа наследника C#

Tags: c#, наследование, доступ

как сделать чтобы у наследника был модификатор public а у родителя нет. И можно ли?
C#

Comment: А зачем? Какой use case? Это точно должен быть один и тот же метод?

Comment: модификатор чего?

Comment: А какой у родителя Вы хотите модификатор поставить и зачем?

Comment: Возможно, автор имеет ввиду `abstract` - родителя. Т.е. мы не можем создать родителя, но можем создать наследника.

Comment: Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Базовый класс необходимо скрыть и объявить protected. Наследник с той же функциональностью должен быть public. Я так понял, что этого сделать нельзя принципиально - т.е. повысить доступность...